# Remove transitive classpath dependency in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, dependency-management

we're running a spring-boot app with gradle.

In order to include the spring-boot plugin we add it as dependency:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.2.RELEASE") 
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this plugin ships with a dependency to
`org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.4.1`

Which I'd like to exclude.

Already tried that by adding:

```
  dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.2.RELEASE") {
            exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j'
        }
    }
```

Which doesn't work.

Also adding:

```
configurations {
    classpath.exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-slf4j-impl'
}
```

Doesn't have any effect.

Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the issue was that I declared log4j as runtime dependency:

```
  ext {
       log4jVersion="2.5"
  }
  runtime (
            "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:$log4jVersion",
            "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:$log4jVersion",
            "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:$log4jVersion"
        )
```

Which lead to the case that version 2.4.1 was fetched by some editor magic as compile dependency.

Therfore I had then 2.4.1 and 2.5 on the classpath.

As soon as I declared log4j as compile dependency 2.4.1 is gone...

Answer (score 8):

If you're trying to exclude

```
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.4.1
```

Try

```
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.2.RELEASE") {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-slf4j-impl'
    }
}
```

Comment: waiiiit a minute! [spring-boot-gradle-plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.3.2.RELEASE) doesn't have log4j-slf4j-impl as a transitive dependency. It is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Mhm no, as soon as I remove it from the gradle script, the dependency is also gone.

Comment: See all transitive dependencies using gradle dependencies task: https://gist.github.com/foragerr/3dcd361f8f277d100325

Comment: Sorry but the gradle plugin doesn't occur in the dependencies graph at all. The reason why i think it's the plugin, is that as soon as I remove it the dependency is gone also. In the dependencies tree I only see version 2.4.1 with (*) which means, enforced by rule.

Comment: true, but you can create a new build.gradle with [this content](https://gist.github.com/foragerr/548ca17cdd16e4492698) and then run gradle dependencies, you will see the tree I posted in the earlier gist. slf4j-impl clearly isn't a transitive dependency of the spring-boot plugin. As for where it *does* come from, I'm a bit lost. Can you post your entire build.gradle?

Comment: Can you please also try : `configurations.classpath.exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-slf4j-impl'` both in and outside the buildscript block.

Comment: Actually you are right, the issue is somewhere else. I just created a new project with the same buildscript and the dependency doesn't appear.

Answer (score 5):

I usually fallback to this when i want to make sure that a dependency never added to a project.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version '2.4.1'
}
```

But are you sure you need to exclude the dependency. It should not be part of the build jar/war.
You can check all dependencies using "gradlew dependencies".

Comment: this won't work since I'd like to use version 2.5 of it. Sorry I didn't mention that in the question.

Comment: I didn't used it before but you can add also the version to the exclude. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: No this is not possible

Answer (score 5):

Two steps, chase down the transitive dependency then exclude it from the library responsible.

`gradle dependencies` gives you the full list including the transitive.  If your project is small that can be helpful but for large enterprise builds... its too much info.  Feel free to search through it but we get more to the point information from `dependencyInsight`.

`gradle dependencyInsight --dependency someDependency` finds all the places the  dependency could come into the build.  If you have multiple versions this will help make it apparent where the versions originate.

In my usecase logging is explicitly declared as a compile time dependency so it shows as below.  If `log4j` was anywhere else you would see the offending library as well as the compile time declaration for v`2.5`.

I had to run this explicitly on each sub module.

```
$ gradle util:dependencyInsight --dependency org.apache.logging.log4j
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:util:dependencyInsight
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.5
+--- compile
\--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.5
     \--- compile

org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.5
\--- compile

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.933 secs
```

Now once you know where to exclude the dependency from just do like before to remove it.  You can confirm by running the `dependencyInsights` again

```
dependencies {
    // found through `gradle dependencyInsight --dependency org.apache.logging.log4j`
    classpath("someOtherGroup:someOtherArtifactId:1.0") {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-slf4j-impl'
    }
}
```

Another solution could be overriding the dependency resolver and force the version to `2.5`

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == "org.apache.logging.log4j") {
            println "Updating version for: $details.requested.group:$details.requested.name:$details.requested.version --> 2.5"
            details.useVersion '2.5'
        }
    }
}
```

My opinion, I probably don't want to keep adding checks in the `resolutionStrategy` all the time so probably better to just track it down in the `dependencyInsights`.  Also this means updating the version in two places and if another developer isn't aware of how gradle's `resolutionStrategy` works then they will have "weird" behavior... eg. I updated `log4j` to `2.7` but it still builds with `2.5`?!?!

But both are valid approaches